# How to record the desktop in VLC media player - second screen

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a dual-head monitor setup under Windows 7, and I want to capture the desktop in VLC media player. But the second screen is preferred. How do I do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to define an offset for the capture.

My screens have a horizontal resolution of 1920px.  So to record my 2nd screen (located to the right of my primary screen), I add `:screen-left=1920` to the "Edit Options" box.  Make sure you check the "Show more options" on the "Open media" dialogue box to see the option.

You can also record just a subset of your screen or monitors located above or below your main screen, etc.  VLC really is amazing.

[image: VLC Capture Settings]

Check out the VLC Command Line Options for all the available flags you can pass in:

```
Screen Input
      --screen-fps=<float>       Frame rate
          Desired frame rate for the capture.
      --screen-top=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
                                 Subscreen top left corner
          Top coordinate of the subscreen top left corner.
      --screen-left=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
                                 Subscreen top left corner
          Left coordinate of the subscreen top left corner.
      --screen-width=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
                                 Subscreen width
          Subscreen width
      --screen-height=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
                                 Subscreen height
          Subscreen height
      --screen-follow-mouse, --no-screen-follow-mouse
                                 Follow the mouse (default disabled)
          Follow the mouse when capturing a subscreen. (default disabled)
      --screen-mouse-image=<string>
                                 Mouse pointer image
          If specified, will use the image to draw the mouse pointer on the
          capture.
      --screen-fragment-size=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
                                 Capture fragment size
          Optimize the capture by fragmenting the screen in chunks of
          predefined height (16 might be a good value, and 0 means disabled).
```

Source: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Comment: Is this answer applicable for Ubuntu also? I have tried both `:screen-width=1920` & `screen-left=1920` but it does not work

Comment: @ScottAnderson, check the resolution of your monitor on the left. For example, mine is 2048x1152. So to record only the right monitor, I use `:screen-left=2048` which means, recording starts from 2049 on, and skips/ignore all of the left screen.

Comment: 'Display settings' labels my primary screen (`Make this my main screen` checked) as 2. When I record with `:screen-left=1920` it records screen 1 (which is actually on the right). So `:screen-left` in VLC terms means the logical screen 1 which is not always the left or primary screen