# Record screen via other PC

Tags: hdmi, recording, screen-recorder

While using OBS for capturing the (audio+video) input for now, it gets quite laggy, as my working PC (a dated T420-Laptop) cannot handle larger applications (Visual Studio etc.) at the same time, it will become unresponsive and laggy.

So I need to seperate the screen-capture from the actual computer.
Buying some external capture-cards is *not* an option.

I have an unused PC around. Is it possible to 'mirror' the screen on my laptop and capture the output (via HDMI or VGA) on the other pc?
Or maybe it is possible to send the screen over the local network to the other pc, if there is no such thing as HDMI-IN?
Does this work 'out of the box' or is there any 3rd party software required, if so, which? (preferrably free software)
I have Win7 & Win10 available, also I don't mind installing a linux distribution on the other pc.

Comment: "if there is no such thing as HDMI-IN?" - This indeed does not exist.

Comment: I haven't found any information regarding capturing the screen externally via another pc and *not* a special capture card. I cannot buy something that expensive (~100$) only for not having the workload on the main machine. I have had my fingers crossed, maybe there is a method somehow..

Comment: While not perfect, without additional hardware, your likely limited to something like this solution.  [How to record the desktop in VLC media player - second screen](http://superuser.com/questions/782959/how-to-record-the-desktop-in-vlc-media-player-second-screen)

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks! But isn't this the same as OBS them?